# Noun phrase involving "of", plural or singular

Tags: noun-phrases, verb-agreement

I feel that the singular form should be correct, but I'm not sure:

"The thickness of papers IS .."

"The thickness of papers ARE .."

By the way, will it change the result, if we use another noun instead of "thickness"?

Comment: Would you please provide more context? Are you talking about any papers, a particular set of papers, or paper in general?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. As @jeff-semmens pointed out, I should have used the definite article in the question. So, it's "The thickness of the papers".
But I also wondered if that matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific example you provided, I would choose "is" as the correct wording and recommend the usage of a definite article:

> The thickness of **the** papers is 2mm.

For other nouns, the answer could be more nuanced depending on what you want to convey. For example:

> The color of the papers is green.
>
> The color**s** of the papers are red, green, and blue.

Whether the noun inside the phrase "of the papers" is plural or not does not impact the usage of plural or singular form for the subject of the sentence (color/colors), only the number of colors, thicknesses, etc does.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was clarifying.